# Merging product not working

Tags: magento-1.9

On my website after login product marge not working in some customer

Let us assume I added one product into the cart after that I logged in but before adding the product did not merge into my cart. Old product only is there. How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you tried Persistent shopping cart

Comment: can you please explain this if i enable what it will do